# Wireshark decrypts ssl packages but does not display http entries

Tags: http, ssl, wireshark

I'm trying to decode a http ssl stream using wireshark and keys exported from firefox via setting the SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable.

The decryption itself works since I'm able to see the decoded data (or spdy packages if spdy is used) by right clicking on a TLSPacket and selecting "Follow SSL Stream".

However Wireshark does not display the HTTP requests and responses as own protocol entries which makes it difficult to analyze multiple streams over a longer period of time.

Does anybody know why this is happening and what I can do to force the detection of HTTP packages in decrypted traffic?